# Nokia S60 oma dm/client provisioning

Tags: qt, nokia, provisioning, s60, oma

I am looking for a very basic provisioning example. I have a wap provisioning file that I just want to use to configure my device.

I am looking for API with example that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try [S60 Platform: OMA Client Provisioning](http://www.vallejo.cc/proyectos/envio%20sms_files/S60_Platform_OMA_Client_Provisioning_v2_0_en.pdf) and [Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/search/search.xhtml?view=ebs&view=ebs&box=1&s=fe&k=oma%20dm%20provisioning).

Comment: Already tried that.. I am not finding any concrete answers and most of them obsolete or require some elaborate gateway setups.